# If statements with 3+ variable comparisons using && or alternate options

Tags: java

I'm attempting the below:

```
if(p1S > p2S && p3S)

}
```

But the IDE doesn't like the && here.

So, how would I compare these 3 ints to find the one with the highest value, thus moving forward.

Aka: If Int 1 is greater than int 2, and int 3, then do this. . .

I suspect I just don't know the syntax well enough just yet (I've only just started college for CS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
if(p1S > p2S && p1S > p3S)

}
```

The reason the previous code didn't work is that the first part

```
if(p1S > p2S && p3S)

}
```

evaluates to:

```
if(boolean && p3S)

}
```

And you can't do an && between a boolean and an int.

Comment: Yep! That's exactly what I needed! 

I didn't realize you needed to specify p1S again before the second comparison. 

Very much appreciated!

Comment: Could also do (just for demonstration purpose): `if(p1 > Math.max(p2,p3))`